# Understanding how to use classes properly in Python

Tags: python, class, pytorch

I am trying to understand how to use concrete examples of classes in Python(more particularly in Pytorch).I have the two following classes:

```
class Context:

    def __init__(self):
        self._saved_tensors = ()
    def save_for_backward(self, *args):
        self._saved_tensors = args
    @property
    def saved_tensors(self):
        return self._saved_tensors



class MSE(Function):

@staticmethod
def forward(ctx, yhat, y):
   
    ctx.save_for_backward(yhat,y)

    return (1/(yhat.shape[0])*((yhat-y)**2)).sum()
@staticmethod
def backward(ctx, grad_output):

    yhat, y = ctx.saved_tensors
    out_weight =grad_output*(2/(yhat.shape[0])*(y-yhat)).sum()
    out_bias =(2/(yhat.shape[0])*(y-yhat)).sum()
    return out_weight,out_bias
```

and when i apply it to the following example:

```
ctx=LinearFunction()
#identity matrix of size 3
yhat=torch.eye(3)
y=torch.ones(3,3)
grad_output=1
loss=MSE(ctx,yhat,y)
loss.backward(ctx,grad_output)
```

it returns me an error:

```
4 grad_output=1
5 loss=MSE(ctx,yhat,y)
6 loss.backward(ctx,grad_output)

<ipython-input-38-0c861407599f> in backward(ctx, grad_output)
   13 def backward(ctx, grad_output):
   15 yhat, y = ctx.saved_tensors
   16 out_weight = (2/(yhat.shape[0])*(y-yhat)).sum()
   17 out_bias =(2/(yhat.shape[0])*(y-yhat)).sum()

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

and the code shows an arrow pointing to lines 6 and 15 indicating the error comes from there.
I understand the code needs yhat and y but I already defined them.So why does the compiler not use them?
Could someone help me out on this? Thank you.

Comment: `ctx.saved_tensors` was an empty sequence or iterable rather than containing two values like you expected it to.

Comment: i am new to computer science,and i am not quite sure to understand your answer.Could you be more specific?Thanks

Comment: You wanted to unpack it into two separate variables, `yhat` and `y`, similar to `a, b = [3, 8]`. But the thing you're unpacking is empty, like an empty list `[]`. So it needed two values for those two variables, but got 0 values. Try printing `ctx.saved_tensors` before using it to see what you're working with.